# How to get drawable metadata from manifest file to android library project

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification, android-manifest, manifest

I have an android library project which will handle push notifications. This library have its fcm receiver that will generate the notification on the behalf of the application which is using this library. 
Here, in the applications Manifest.xml, I am adding notification icon as meta data as follows.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="notification_big_icon"
        android:value="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="notification_small_icon"
        android:value="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I want to parse this these drawable resources into the library project and set the notification icons. How can I achieve this.

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: I got it working atlast. thanks.

Comment: ApplicationInfo ai = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
            small_icon = bundle.getInt("notification_small_icon", 0);

Comment: Just adding a missing piece to @HarikrishnanCV answer, in the metadata tag, instead of using android:value, use android:resource to get the numeric ID of the resource otherwise with the code posted in his comment, it will give an exception of String value when int value is expected. Mentioned in the metadata documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element